# Input array codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i have form dinamic in like this

[image: my image]

i am creating a dynamic form, i have an add button, when i click it adds one line to the form.

but when I echo , why is it like this ?

this my code

```
 public function inputData(){
        $provinsi = $this->input->post('provinsi');
        $res = array();
        for ($i=0; $i < count($provinsi); $i++) { 
            $res[] = array(
                'id_finance' => '1',
                'provinsi'   => $provinsi[$i],
            );
         $this->db->insert_batch('lokasi', $res);
         echo "<pre>", print_r($res);
        }
    }
```

this output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_finance] => 1
            [provinsi] => TES 1
        )
)
1
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_finance] => 1
            [provinsi] => TES 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_finance] => 1
            [provinsi] => TES 2
        )
)
1

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_finance] => 1
            [provinsi] => TES 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_finance] => 1
            [provinsi] => TES 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_finance] => 1
            [provinsi] => TES 3
        )
)
1
```

i want it like this for output , how to ?

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id_finance] => 1
                [provinsi] => TES 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id_finance] => 1
                [provinsi] => TES 2
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [id_finance] => 1
                [provinsi] => TES 3
            )
    )
```

this my form

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'testing/inputData'; ?>">
          <div>
               <input type="text" name="provinsi[]"class="form-control name_list"/>
               <button type="button" name="add">Add More</button>
          </div>                       
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">submit</button>
 </form>
```

to add a row I use jquery help.

how to make output like above? where is the error code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the array for each loop, try this:

```
 public function inputData(){
        $provinsi = $this->input->post('provinsi');
        $res = array();
        for ($i=0; $i < count($provinsi); $i++) { 
            $res[] = array(
                'id_finance' => '1',
                'provinsi'   => $provinsi[$i],
            );
         $this->db->insert_batch('lokasi', $res);
        }
        echo "<pre>", print_r($res);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**View:-**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'testing/inputData'; ?>">
          <div>
               <input type="text" name="provinsi[]" class="form-control name_list"/>
               <button type="button" name="add">Add More</button>
          </div>                       
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">submit</button>
 </form>
```

**Controller Code:-**

```
public function inputData(){
        $mainarray = array();
        $data= $this->input->post();
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data['provinsi']); $i++) {
           $arr = array(
                'id_finance'=>'1',
                'provinsi'=>$data['provinsi'][$i],
                $mainarray[] =  $arr;               
        }
       $table="table_name";
    $result=$this->db->insert_batch($table,$mainarray); 
     }
```

Comment: thanks all , i wan to try again